# How to use preg_replace to replace text between different delimiters () {} [] <> and how to escape these delimiters when needed?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I think that one of the common uses of `preg_replace` is to replace a pattern enclosed by delimiters such as parenthesis`()`, square brackets `[]`, curly brackets`{}`, angle brackets`<>`, double quotes `""`, single quotes ``` `` ```, ...

What I learned from the [PHP site](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) is that often used delimiters are forward slashes (/), hash signs (#) and tildes (~). This is confusing either after testing some  replacements

For Example

```
function replace_delimiters($text) {
    $text = preg_replace('/\((.*?)\)/', 'This replaces text between parenthesis', $text);  //working
    $text = preg_replace('/\[(.*?)\]/', 'This replaces text between square brackets', $text);  //working
    $text = preg_replace('/`([^`]*)`/', 'This replaces the text between single quotes', $text);  //working 
    $text = preg_replace('/\`(.*?)\`/', 'This replaces the text between single quotes', $text); //working
    $text = preg_replace('/(?<!\\\\)`((?:[^`\\\\]|\\\\.)*)`/', 'This replaces the text between single quotes', $text); //working
    $text = preg_replace('/\<(.*?)\>/', 'This replaces the text between angle quotes', $text);   // Not working
    $text = preg_replace('/"[^"]*"/', 'This replaces the text between double quotes', $text);   // Not working

    return $text;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'replace_delimiters');
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'replace_delimiters');
```

I need to know

1. How to change this code so that I could replace text between double quotes `""` and angle quotes`<>`
2. What is the difference between using

   '/`([^`]*)`/'

and

```
'/\`(.*?)\`/'
```

For single quotes delimiters.

3. How to escape these delimiters (using a backslash for example) so that they are not treated as special characters?

Comment: `(.*?)` - matches anything "non-greedy" none or more, `([^']*)` anything not `'` none or more.

Comment: `is that often used delimiters are forward slashes (/), hash signs (#) and tildes (~)`  these are delimiters for the regex. `/(.*?)/` , `#(.*?)#` or `~(.*?)~`  you can use anything you want for these as long as they dont have special meaning in regex (like `?` or `+` have special meaning) and you have to escape any occurrence of the delimiter in the pattern, so most people use something not in the pattern.  For example if you use a URL `yourdomain.com/foo` you may not want to use `/` as the denim because it naturally appears in the pattern, so we need to escape it `/yourdomain.com\/foo/`

Comment: Be aware that preg_replace also replaces your delimiters and not the stuff that is between them (i dont mean the forward slashes at the beginning and end of the regex string)